# Button to cycle through 3 state changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick, toggle, state

I'm new to JS and working on a class assignment that requires:

When the user clicks the highlight button apply a css class to every other li element so you get the colors alternating, and make an image appear.

I'm having trouble getting the toggle for the color changes to work and I can't get the image to show up either.

```
    <script>

        var colors = new Array()
        colors[0] = "#cc0099";
        colors[1] = "#a4c400";
        colors[2] = "#9900cc";

        var counter = 0;

        window.onload = function()
        {
            var highlightBtn= document.getElementById("highlight_btn");
            highlightBtn.onclick = switchColors;
        }

        function switchColors()
        {   
            var imgSrc = "images/" + [i];
            var changeLI = document.getElementsByClassName("change");
            changeLI.innerHTML = counter;
            counter++;              
        }

    </script>

    <h1>Happy Mothers Day!</h1>
    <h2>Things to get Mom:</h2>

    <ul>
        <li class="change">New Plants</li>
        <li>Flowers</li>
        <li class="change">A Day at the Spa</li>
        <li>A Picture of Yourself</li>
        <li class="change">New Shoes!</li>
        <li>Anything with a Heart on It</li>
        <li class="change"> Chocolate</li>
    </ul>

    <input id="highlight_btn" type="button" value="Highlight">
```

Comment: I was copying from my notes and that was my shorthand for document.getElementsbyClassName. I have since fixed it.

Comment: var imgSrc = "images/" + [i]; should be var imgSrc = "images/" + images[counter]; and then you need an image array too. Also you try to assign the value of the counter to an array of LIs

Answer (score 0):

Use getElementsByClassName instead of getClass, which is not even defined on document. To change colours, use the Element.style.color property.

```
var changeLi = document.getElementsByClassName("change");

for(var i = 0; i < changeLi.length; i ++) {
    changeLi[i].style.color = colors[i];
});
```

Comment: I changed the getClass to getByCLassName, but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (its not clear as to what you want exactly), but this shows you the principles.

HTML

```
<h1>Happy Mothers Day!</h1>
<h2>Things to get Mom:</h2>
<img id="mom" src="">
<ul>
    <li class="change">New Plants</li>
    <li>Flowers</li>
    <li class="change">A Day at the Spa</li>
    <li>A Picture of Yourself</li>
    <li class="change">New Shoes!</li>
    <li>Anything with a Heart on It</li>
    <li class="change">Chocolate</li>
</ul>
<input id="highlight_btn" type="button" value="Highlight">
```

Javascript

```
var colors = [];
var images = [];
var counter1 = 0;
var counter2 = 0;

colors.push("#cc0099");
colors.push("#a4c400");
colors.push("#9900cc");

images.push("http://imageshack.us/scaled/thumb/104/9071003006mini2lpl0.jpg");
images.push("http://imageshack.us/scaled/thumb/121/spirra.jpg");
images.push("http://imageshack.us/scaled/thumb/123/s4020001ret9qr.jpg");

function switchColors() {
    var changes = document.getElementsByClassName("change");

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(changes, function (change) {
        change.style.backgroundColor = colors[counter1];
    });

    counter1 += 1;
    if (counter1 > colors.length - 1) {
        counter1 = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById("mom").src = images[counter2];
    counter2 += 1;
    if (counter2 > images.length - 1) {
        counter2 = 0;
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    document.getElementById("highlight_btn").addEventListener("click", switchColors, false);
}, false);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/s9eku/)

Comment: To be more clear, when you push the button the 1st time, colorA should  be applied to every other li and imageA should show up. When you click it again, colorB is applied and imageB shows up, etc. Until you have cycled through colorsA-C and returned to the default state.

Comment: The above demonstrates cycling through 3 states as specified in your original question and title.